# access the element of multidimensional array given the subscript array

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

Given a multidimensional array `A = MxMxMx...xM`, where `ndims(A)=n` and the subscript array `b=[a1, a2, ..., an]`. How to get `A(a1, a2, a3, ..., an)`? I've tried `A(b)`. It's not a correct way. And a correct way is to write a function to convert the subscript array to the index, saying `i`, and then we can use `A(i)` to get what I want. Is there an easier way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that, the easiest way would be through [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511), using, e.g. [sub2ind](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) function.

```
BasCell = num2cell(b);    
i = sub2ind(size(A), BasCell{:});
A(i); % access ith element in A, using linear indexing
```